# How to add and remove a table from jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add and later to remove a table with all rows from jquery dialog. I would also like to add some css style to this table/rows. 
The table should go into empty div id=dialog-message1.

Could someone help me with this, please?

function script part is attached bellow:

```
$("#dialog-message1").hide();
$('.confirmation1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
    var product_name = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().html();
    console.log(product_name);

    $("#dialog-message1").append("<table id='tableINFO'>");
    $("#dialog-message1").append("<tr><th>Nazwa produktu</th><th>Waga (g)</th><th>Kalorie (Kcal)</th></tr>");
    $("#dialog-message1").append("<tr><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td></tr>");

    $("#dialog-message1").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    //$( "tr" ).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried adding rows and cols, and removing it, but since there was no id provided I could only remove tables from the entire page.

I can see rows, but I cannot remove it.

Comment: it's not clear is this exactly what you need ,But as i understand you need a way to identify rows uniquely?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do.  You've asked how to add/remove a table then shown code that adds it and the table has an id so should be ok to remove *the table* (you could also use `$("#dialog-message1 > table").remove()` if the table didn't have an id.  Did you mean you want to remove specific rows from the table?  How would you/the code know which rows to remove?

Comment: There is a jquery dialog with OK button. The dialog will be used to display product information in a table. There will be only one table containing several rows on this dialog. I do not need to remove any row, I need to remove the entire table. Your way is OK for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/3vdup6jr/

```js
$("#dialog-message1").hide();
$('.confirmation1').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var lnk = $(this).attr('href');
    var product_name = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().html();
    console.log(product_name);

    $("#dialog-message1").append("<table id='tableINFO'><tr><th>Nazwa produktu</th><th>Waga (g)</th><th>Kalorie (Kcal)</th></tr><tr><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td></tr>");

    $("#dialog-message1").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $( "#dialog-message1 table" ).remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog-message1">
</div>
<button class="confirmation1">
CLICK
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The table is binded to the `dialog`, you can try removing its children.

```js
$("#dialog-message1").hide();

$('.confirmation1').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var lnk = $(this).attr('href');

  var product_name = $(this).parents("tr").find("td").first().html();

  // console.log(product_name);

  $("#dialog-message1").append("<table id='tableINFO'>");

  $("#dialog-message1").append("<tr><th>Nazwa produktu</th><th>Waga (g)</th><th>Kalorie (Kcal)</th></tr>");
  $("#dialog-message1").append("<tr><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td><td>Table data</td></tr>");

  $("#dialog-message1").dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Ok: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
        $("#dialog-message1").children().remove();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<button class="confirmation1">Confirm</button>
<div id="dialog-message1"></div>
```